How to download from MicroController Kit to ArduinoNano33IoT?
I am trying to use MicroControllerEmbedCode to download a program to an Arduino NANO 33 IoT using MMA 14, Win 10.
I have successfully done this with an Arduino Uno R3. When the Uno is plugged in to the USB, Win 10 identifies the device as a USB device "Arduino Uno (COM4)". I use "COM4" as the programmer specification and it works.
When I plug the ArduinoNano33IoT into the USB, Win 10 identifies it as a USB device "Arduino NANO 33 IoT" with no com port indicated. However, the Arduino IDE identifies it as "COM5" and can successfully program it.
When I try to program it using the same code as used for the Uno, it appears to generate source code. (Byte count 656) But it then throws an error and the target device does not exectute the code.
Any help is appreciated. Below is the code I am using:
Needs["MicrocontrollerKit`"]

boardName = "ArduinoNano33IoT";

sys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{Which[x > 0, 0, True, 
      1]}, {x}}, {x}, {}, {Automatic}, Automatic, SamplingPeriod -> 1];

sys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{Which[x > 0, 0, True, 
      1]}, {x}}, {x}, {}, {Automatic}, Automatic, SamplingPeriod -> 1];

\[Mu]c = <|"Target" -> boardName, "Outputs" -> 13 -> "Digital"|>;

p = {"COM5"};

mdata = MicrocontrollerEmbedCode[sys, \[Mu]c, p];

(*First: {} has zero length and no first element*)

mdata["SourceCodeByteCount"]

(*656*)

